# UnitTest checking title of UINavigation returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm just starting learning TDD concepts and trying to write my tests.
At first, I want to check if the title of my ViewController is equal to what I want.

I have a very simple class for my VC:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Discover"
    }

}
```

And in my tests I'm checking as:

```
func test_titleShouldBe_Discover() {
    sut = MyViewController()

    XCTAssertEqual(sut.title, "Discover")
}
```

and I get in my test this error:

```
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to ("Optional("Discover")")
```

Can someone tell me where I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because `viewDidLoad()` is not automatically called after `init`. Add a call to load the view:

```
func test_titleShouldBe_Discover() {
    sut = MyViewController()
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.title, "Discover")
}
```

Comment: yes, I thought about that also, but when I put breakpoints the it stopped firstly at `didLoad` and just later at `XCTAssertEqual`

Comment: So if you add that line, the test still fails? That should not be the case.

Comment: The breakpoint you added may be getting hit from a different test.

Comment: but yes, you are right! And also it's not a good approach to call `viewDidLoad` directly. The better way is to use `loadViewIfNeeded()`

Comment: Yep, that is better. Editing my answer.